# willSelectRowAt and didSelectRowAt not called anymore since Xcode 9 / Swift 4

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift4, xcode9

Since I've upgraded to Xcode 9 / Swift 4 some of my `UITableViewDelegate` methods are not called anymore

Answer (score 0):

As of Xcode 9 / Swift 4 all Objective-C methods should be marked `@objc`. The compiler does a reasonable job of recognizing where it should be applied however it doesn't figure out inheritance. For example:

```
class Delegate: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate {
}

class SuperDelegate: Delegate {
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? { return indexPath }
}
```

This will not generate any warning, crashing or build error. However your line will not be called until you add `@objc`:

```
@objc class SuperDelegate: Delegate {
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? { return indexPath }
}
```